# Vowel Removal C++ :: Compiles/Runs, but SENTINEL issue.

Tags: c++

Alright, so this code works. WOOHOO. My problem now is that I need help figuring out how to make the Sentinel work.

When I run and enter 0 to test sentinel function, I get:

1

The word(s) entered reflecting only consonants: 0

Alos, does anybody know where this "1" is coming from? It's part of the output when I use a word, too....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void removeVowel(string&);            // Removes vowels from input string.
string withVowel;                     // Will be used to read user input. 

int main ()
{   

    const int SENTINEL = 0;           // Sentinel value. 

    // Request input string unless sentinel is entered.  

    cout << "Enter a word or series of words. " << '\n';
    cout << "Or, enter " << SENTINEL << " to quit. " << endl;
    cin >> withVowel;

    // Run loop.

    removeVowel(withVowel);

    // Display the string without vowels.

    cout << "The word(s) entered reflecting only consonants :" << withVowel << endl;

    return 0;
}

    void removeVowel(string& withVowel)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int length = int(withVowel.length());
        while (i < length)
    {
        if (withVowel.at(i) == 'a' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'A' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'e' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'E' ||
            withVowel.at(i) == 'i' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'I' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'o' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'O' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'u' ||
            withVowel.at(i) == 'U')

            {
                withVowel.erase(i, 1);
                length = int(withVowel.length());
            }
            else i++; 
        }

    // Display the string without vowels.   

    cout << removeVowel << endl;

    }
```

Comment: You misspelled `main`.

Comment: @user, `std::getline` takes a `std::string` to read into, not an `int`.

Comment: `getline(cin, char withVowel, '\n');` makes no sense. Tell us what you were trying to do with it and we may be able to help.

Comment: Ha. Main. Okay, well I don't know what I'm doing because no I have plethora of errors...

Comment: Oh, I was trying to use the getline to call the users input, so that way it would read the input and remove the vowels? Should I not do that...?

Comment: When I saw the title I thought "Welsh"

Comment: Please stop morphing the question. If you keep changing the question, then you invalidate previous answers, and the question does not become useful to other people with the same problem.

Comment: Okay, what should I do rather than editing the question?? Sorry, I'm new....obviously.

Comment: Stick to the original question. It is a moving target

Comment: But the original question has evolved......So in the forums how do I post my questions that have evolved from that question while displaying my code?????? Yall are telling me not to do something but not enabling me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 signatures of `getline()` are:

```
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);
```

You have the variable `withVowel` declared as a `std::string` in the global scope, and then you have it declared as an `int` in `main`.

This is not valid syntax:

```
 getline(cin, char withVowel, '\n');
```

If you wanted to cast `withVowel` to a `char` you should use the following syntax:

```
(char) withVowel
```

In any case, the 2nd argument to `getline()` needs to be of type `std::string`.

Comment: Okay, the withVowel is meant to be assigned as the cin for the compiler to read the users input and use the loop to remove the vowels. I am thinking that shouldn't even be a char?

Comment: I changed it to getline(cin, withVowel), and lost the error. But now I have error "[Error] no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'const int')"

Comment: change your `while` loop to a `for` loop to index into the string: `for (int i = 0; i < withVowel.size(); i++)` then you access the character with `withVowel[i]`

Comment: Thanks so much @unluddite! That worked, but I have one last error. It says "Error] switch quantity not an integer".

I know I have switch(withVowel), so do I need to change this to i=0 or something?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to do.
I tried to write something that works, you can start from there

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


bool string_has_vowel(string s);
bool char_is_vowel(char c);

string SENTINEL="0";


int main ()
{
    string user_input[1000];

    cout << "Enter a word or series of words. " << endl;
    cout << "Or, enter \"" << SENTINEL << "\" to quit. " << endl;

    int input_lines=0;
    for(;input_lines<1000;input_lines++)
    {
        cin >> user_input[input_lines];
        if(user_input[input_lines]==SENTINEL)
            break;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<input_lines;i++)
    {
        if(string_has_vowel(user_input[i]))
            cout << "The word(s) entered reflecting only consonants :" << user_input[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}

bool string_has_vowel(string s)
{
    for(int j=0;j<s.size();j++)
    {
        if( char_is_vowel(s[j]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
bool char_is_vowel(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
        {
            return true;
        }
        default:
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```