# Sentinel not working?

Tags: c++11

I'm not sure why this isn't working, but this is my error message:

Error] no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' and 'const int')

EDIT: The above issue has been resolved. But, the current issues are redundant `***`, and the lack of vowel removal in a sentence rather than just the first word of a sentence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void removeVowel(string&);      // Removes vowels from input string.
string withVowel;               // Will be used to read user input. 

int main ()
{   

    const string SENTINEL = "0";        // Sentinel value. 

    // Request input string unless SENTINEL is entered.  

    cout << "Enter a word or series of words. " << '\n';
    cout << "Or, enter " << SENTINEL << " to quit. " << endl;
    cin >> withVowel;

    // In case of SENTINEL:

    while (withVowel == SENTINEL)
    {
        cout << "***" << endl;
    }

    // Run loop.

    removeVowel(withVowel);

    // Display the string without vowels.

    cout << "The word(s) entered reflecting only consonants: " << withVowel << endl;

    return 0;
}

    void removeVowel(string& withVowel)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int length = int(withVowel.length());
        while (i < length)
    {
        if (withVowel.at(i) == 'a' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'A' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'e' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'E' ||
            withVowel.at(i) == 'i' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'I' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'o' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'O' || 
            withVowel.at(i) == 'u' ||
            withVowel.at(i) == 'U')

            {
                withVowel.erase(i, 1);
                length = int(withVowel.length());
            }
            else i++; 
        }

    // Display the string without vowels.   

    cout << removeVowel << endl;

    }
```

Comment: What type is `withVowel`?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my post and show my whole code so it makes more sense.

Comment: Can you do something about the formatting? I mean, remove the leading `>` signs and fix the indentation & line breaks.

Comment: As for word vs. sentence - look up (e.g. on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)) how `>>` treats whitespace, and what other ways of input exist (such as `std::getline` or `std::basic_istream::getline`). But that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22286155/1782465), and the error message, I assume `withVowel` is a `std::string`. The error message is pretty much telling you what the problem is: you can't compare a `std::string` with an `int`.

Since you only need `SENTINEL` for printing and comparison, just declare it as a `std::string` as well:

```
const std::string SENTINEL = "0";
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks Angew. I did what you suggested, and am now getting some crazy error when I run after a compile?? It opens and says "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error"

Comment: Alright so nevermind that. I don't know what was happening, but it stopped. Now my SENTINEL is working, but I need it to displace *** for SENTINEL. It is, but it's displaying *** endlessly. Can I make that stop?

Comment: @whatsHerFace You put the `***` display into a `while` loop, whose condition is not changed in its body. So of course it loops forever. If the program is supposed to end when `SENTINTEL` is input, simply change the `while` loop into `if (withVowel == SENTINEL) { cout << "***\n"; return 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare *const int* with *strings*.
Use *ctrl+z* and *enter* to stop the input.

```
string word;    
cout << "ctrl+z and Enter to exit\n";
while (cin >> word){
    cout << word << ' ';
    // other processing
}
```

And for your case:

```
cout << "Enter a word or series of words.\n";     
cout << "Ctrl+z and Enter to exit\n";
while (cin >> withVowel){
    removeVowel(withVowel);
    cout << "The word(s) entered reflecting only consonants :" << withVowel << endl;
}
```